# State Tax on Sale of Michigan S-Corp for Non-Resident

Tags: united-states, small-business, state-income-tax, s-corporation

I have a family member that will be a resident of Florida for 2019.  He is contemplating selling his business based in Michigan (S-Corp).  He can run the business remotely (but anticipates spending some time in Michigan, though meaningfully less than 183 days).  The sale will be structured as an asset sale.

Would he pay Michigan state tax on the proceeds of the sale?

Thanks

Comment: Does the business have a physical presence in Michigan?

Comment: yes, business has physical presence in Michigan